# Configure Router for better DDoS protection Actiontec MI424WR

Tags: router, denial-of-service

So for the past month, my server has been attacked by script-kiddies three times. The server is mainly used as a minecraft server. I am getting worried that this is becoming an outbreak as many of these people are coming from minecraft and are probably between the ages of 12 and 16.

To hopefully stop basic attacks, I am thinking about really locking down my router to only manage legitimate inbound traffic and try to drop invalid inbound traffic as best as I can.

The router I am using is: Actiontec MI424WR

I have been peaking through my router configuration settings and found a section on 'Advanced Filtering'.

In the advanced filtering options there is a list of all the devices. That thing that peaked my interest and inspired me to write this question is I can setup Ethernet/Coax and Broadband Connection (Ethernet/Coax) rules.

The idea is to only allow packets that I know are meant for the applications that I am hosting from my server. I have the ports associated with these applications and I have setup port forwarding rules for these services. I am hoping to lock down things even further by adding rules for the actual coax so as soon as packets come through, I can just drop the bad packets.

I understand that this will not block large DDoS attacks, but I'm hoping to just stop the script-kiddies from taking things down. (I only have a 35mbit up/down connection.)

Questions:

(1) In advanced filtering there are two sets of rules: (a) Ethernet/Coax Rules and (b) Broadband Connection (Ethernet/Coax) Rules. What is the difference between these listed devices?

(2) Given a list of open ports for my server, would it be safe to just add a set of rules to the Ethernet/Coax rules in advanced filtering, or have I missed something here? My family connects to this network, so I do not want to prevent them from being able to use the internet and applications such as skype.

Finally, if there are any tips/advice that I could get, I would greatly appreciate it. This issue seems to be spinning out of control as I have seen thousands of servers just getting hammered by these script-kiddies. I am planning on setting up the following rules in the meantime: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2006/07/10/configure-your-router-to-block-dos-attempts.aspx

Comment: Do you know what kind of attacks these are, specifically?  If they're DDoS attacks, they're likely aimed at saturating your bandwidth.  In that case, filtering the traffic at your router won't help, as the traffic has already traversed the bottleneck between you and your ISP - dropping it after the damage has been done won't help.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not having sufficient logging enabled to detect the exact type. Since the attack I have added the logging to view it if it were to happen again. So is the only real option to purchase DDoS protection for my personal server (which can be pricy)?

Comment: Essentially, yes - if something's saturating your bandwidth upstream of the devices you control, then it needs to be mitigated upstream as well.  Sometimes your ISP might be able to help with blocking the attack traffic without any extra charge.